# How to specify XML element names in bpmn-js

Tags: bpmn, bpmn.io

If I define a moddle file with bpmn-js like this

```
    {
        name: "thisArgument",
        superClass: [
            "Element"
        ],
        properties: []
    },
    {
        name: "myData",
        superClass: [
            "Element"
        ],
        properties: [
            {
                name: "argument",
                type: "thisArgument"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Then the resulting XML (when I call saveXML) will have an element called `thisArgument`, despite the fact that the name is "argument".  First, is that a bug?  If not, how do I control the output so that the XML contains `argument` rather than `thisArgument`?  I've searched the docs and examples but can't find how to do this.

The only workaround I found was to make it `type: "argument"` and then define `argument` with a superClass of `thisArgument` and no extra properties (essentially making an alias).  However, that only works if all instances of `argument` are identical.  Eg. if the XML needed to be

```
<A><argument/></A>
<B><argument/></B>
```

where the argument in A has a different shape than the argument in B, then there would be a conflict since I can't define `argument` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can *sort of* answer my own question.  I found this serialize option and experimented, and it mostly does what I want, but sometimes it adds an unwanted `xsi:type="originalType"` attribute and sometimes it doesn't.  Maybe it depends on `isBody` but I'm not sure.  If anyone knows the details of how it works, please reply.

```
properties: [
    {
        name: "argument",
        type: "thisArgument",
        xml: {
            serialize: "xsi:type"
        },
    }
]
```

The closest thing I found to documentation on it is https://forum.bpmn.io/t/bpmn-json-documentation/1304 which describes it as "additional meta-data impecting XML serialization of a type", so I'd appreciate any extra details anyone can supply.

**Update**:
The docs don't mention this, but it turns out that `serialize: "property"` is exactly what I need.  This does the same as `serialize: "xsi:type"` but doesn't add the `xsi:type` attribute.

```
    xml: {
        serialize: "property"
    },
```

I found this by hunting the code in one of the related packages, moddle-xml.

In [write.js](https://github.com/bpmn-io/moddle-xml/blob/master/lib/write.js#L536), there's code that looks for the `xsi:type` or `property` entry:

```
  // allow serialization via type
  // rather than element name
  var asType = serializeAsType(p),
      asProperty = serializeAsProperty(p);
```

In the same file, I found some code that appears to explain why the `xsi:type` didn't always show up, too:

```
  // only serialize xsi:type if necessary
  if (descriptor.name === this.propertyDescriptor.type) {
        return attributes;
  }
```

Comment: Found this eventually: https://github.com/bpmn-io/moddle-xml/blob/master/docs/descriptor-xml.md says "adds additional notes on how to serialize. Supported value(s): xsi:type serializes as data type rather than element".  That doesn't explain the odd `xsi:type` behaviour I found and doesn't mention the  `"serialize": "property"` option I found by hunting the source code.